Unity XR Build and Run no longer working
I have connected the meta quest 3 to my computer via USB cable and allowed debugging on the device.
I have opened the default VR template from Unity Hub, without any alterations.
In Unity I select "build and run" for the default scene. This gives the following messages:

Application installed to device "2G0Y...ZK [Quest 3]".
Build completed with a result of 'Succeeded' in 11 seconds (10622 ms).

The problem is that the app does not appear on the Meta Quest at all...! The quest does not respond at all. There are no error messages.
